# Null pointer exception when changing int in another class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, int

Ive looked and looked and cant find the answer. But here is my issue. I am wanting to change a int in another class based on ticks in the main Game class. Here is the code:

Trace:

```
    02-16 02:10:58.605: W/dalvikvm(1578): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught                 exception (group=0x40c5ca68)
    02-16 02:10:58.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-16720
    02-16 02:10:58.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-16 02:10:58.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at    com.mojang.ld22.Game.tick(Game.java:374)
    02-16 02:10:58.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at   com.mojang.ld22.Game.iterate(Game.java:300)
    02-16 02:10:58.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at com.mojang.ld22.GameActivity$4.run(GameActivity.java:136)
    02-16 02:10:58.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Game.java Snippet

```
    public void tick() {
    tickCount++;

    ...
    ...
    ...

        if (tickCount % 1000 == 0) {
            if (rising) {
                lightlvl++;
Would error here too        clock.time++;    <-----------

                if (lightlvl >= 8) {
                    rising = false;
                }

            } else {
                lightlvl--;
    LINE 374 ---------->        clock.time--;    <------------

                if (lightlvl <= -2) 
                    rising = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And Clock.java

```
    package com.mojang.ld22.entity;

    import com.mojang.ld22.crafting.Crafting;
    import com.mojang.ld22.entity.particle.TextParticle;
    import com.mojang.ld22.entity.particle.TimeClock;
    import com.mojang.ld22.gfx.Color;
    import com.mojang.ld22.gfx.Screen;
    import com.mojang.ld22.screen.CraftingMenu;
    import com.mojang.ld22.item.FurnitureItem;

    public class Clock extends Furniture {


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3146189783597003582L;

Player player;
public int time = 0;
public int clock = 1;
public boolean rising = false;

public Clock() {
    super("Clock");
    col = Color.get(-1, 100, 321, 431);
    sprite = 10;
    xr = 3;
    yr = 2;

}

@Override
public void tick(){
    if (time <= 0)
        clock = 1;
    if (time == 1)
        clock = 1;
    if (time == 2)
        clock = 2;
    if (time == 3)
        clock = 3;
    if (time == 4)
        clock = 4;
    if (time == 5)
        clock = 5;
    if (time == 6)
        clock = 6;
    if (time == 7)
        clock = 7;
    if (time == 8);
        clock = 8;
}



@Override
public void render(Screen screen){
    int col = Color.get(-1, 531, 000, 534);
    //incorrect times TODO
    if (clock == 8)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 7 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
    if (clock == 6)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 8 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
    //noon midnight
    if (clock == 5)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 9 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
    if (clock == 4)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 10 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
    //Before noon after noon
    if (clock == 3)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 11 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
    if (clock == 2)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 12 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
    //730pm 530pm
    if (clock == 1)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 13 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
    if (clock == -1)
        screen.render(x - 8, y - 8, 14 + 11 * 32, col, 0);
}
}
```

And yes this isn't pretty. This is basically what I tried when I couldn't pull any int from game.java to clock.java So this was to test sending it. I cant use separate ticks because clock.java isn't created until the player pulls it from his/her inventory.

I hope this makes since. I can supply more code if you need it.

Comment: You haven't shown how `clock` is declared and initialized in `Game.java`, and that's probably where the problem is. I suspect that `clock` is null, but we can't tell from the information you've given.

Comment: Clock in declared at the top of game.java public Clock clock;

Comment: @user1801875 You need to initialise it: `clock = new Clock();` before you can use it.

Comment: @user1801875: That's where it's declared - but have you *initialized* it? (I'd also strongly encourage you not to use public variables.)

Comment: @assylias trying that now

Comment: clock is null but this really seems very localized

Comment: @assylias It Works. Thank you so much. Now I just need to figure out why the clock sprite isn't updating now.

Answer (score 4):

`rising` is false, so the else branch is executed and `clock` is null, which throws a NullPointerException.

By the way, you could write the tick method like this:

```
public void tick(){
    if (time <= 0) clock = 1;
    else if (time <= 8) clock = time;
}
```

Comment: `public int clock = 1`

Comment: Ok. Must be mislead by the lowercase `clock` in the lines with the arrows

Comment: @user000001 There are 2 `clock` variables: `public int clock = 1` in the Clock class and `public Clock clock;` in the Game class. The latter is null.

Comment: Then you are correct. +1

Comment: Well the game runs fine until the clock becomes in view. The lightlevel ingame works flawlessly. Its not shown but clock is declared at the top of game.java as public Clock clock;

Comment: @assylias so what would be my work around.

Comment: @user1801875 As commented above, you need to initialise the variable before you use it or it will throw a NullPointerException. The easiest way is to change the declaration to `public Clock clock = new Clock();`. Note that using public variables is not recommended.